# Does anyone know how to get Input Director to work with Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1

I've been using Input Director with Windows 7, but now that I've upgraded to 8.1, I find that when I move the mouse cursor to the other computer, the pointer doesn't stay visible.  Clicking works if you can guess where the cursor is.  Obviously this is painful and not practical to keep using.

Has anyone found a way to use InputDirector with Windows 8.1?

Comment: Does running it in Win7 compatibility mode help?

Comment: That did not help.  Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, however if I plug another mouse in to the slave pc, the cursor will appear and work with the mouse on the master pc. A workaround but not perfect.